# How to post an image file with a list of strings using FastAPI?

Tags: python, arrays, post, http-post, fastapi

I have tried a lot of things, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```py
@app.post("/my-endpoint")
async def my_func(
    languages: List[str] = ["en", "hi"], image: UploadFile = File(...)
):
```

The function works fine when I remove one of the parameters, but with both of the parameters, the retrieved list comes out to be like `["en,hi"]`, whereas I want it to be `["en, "hi]`.

I am not even sure if my approach is correct, hence the broader question, if this approach is not right then how can I post a list and an image together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function looks just fine. That behaviour though has to do with how [FastAPI autodocs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#automatic-docs) (Swagger UI)—I am assuming you are using it for testing, as I did myself and noticed the exact same behaviour—handles the `list` items. For some reason, the Swagger UI/OpenAPI adds all items as a single item to the `list`, separated by comma (i.e., `["en, hi, ..."]`, instead of `["en", "hi", ...]`).

Testing the code with Python requests and sending the languages' `list` in the proper way, it works just fine. To fix, however, the behaviour of Swagger UI, or any other tool that might behave the same, you could perform a check on the length of the `list` that is received in the function, and if it is equal to 1 (meaning that the `list` contains a single item), then split this item using `comma` delimiter to get a new `list` with all languages included.

Below is a working example:

**app.py**

```
from fastapi import File, UploadFile, FastAPI
from typing import List

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/submit")
def submit(languages: List[str] = ["en", "hi"], image: UploadFile = File(...)):
        if (len(languages) == 1):
            languages= [item.strip() for item in languages[0].split(',')]
        return {"Languages ": languages, "Uploaded filename": image.filename}
```

**test.py**

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/submit'
image = {'image': open('sample.png', 'rb')}
#payload ={"languages": ["en", "hi"]}  # send languages as separate items
payload ={"languages": "en, hi"}  # send languages as a single item
resp = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, files=image) 
print(resp.json())
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I think I solved this using query parameters. I will post my answer below as well, but I have marked your answer as accepted! Feel free to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using Query parameters! This might be helpful for someone, though I think Chris' answer makes much more sense -

```py
@app.post("/my-endpoint")
async def my_func(
    languages: List[str] = Query(["en", "hi"]), image: UploadFile = File(...)
):
```