# "Value is not a valid email address" when sending multiple email addresses using Pydantic, FastAPI and Swagger UI

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using [`fastapi-mail`](https://github.com/sabuhish/fastapi-mail) package, and trying to send multiple files to multiple email addresses. When I send the email to only one email address, the application works as expected. However, when I change to `List[EmailStr]` for sending to multiple email addresses, I get this error:

```
not a valid email address
```

Here is my code:

```
@app.post("/file")async def send_file(
background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,
email:List[EmailStr] = Form(...), #I Change here before EmailStr = Form(...)
file:Optional[List[UploadFile]] = File(...),) -> JSONResponse:
print(email)
print(file)
message = MessageSchema(
    subject="Fastapi mail module",
    recipients=email,
    body="Simple background task",
    subtype="html",
    attachments=file)

fm = FastMail(ConnectionConfig(
    MAIL_USERNAME=res("MAIL_USERNAME"),
    MAIL_PASSWORD=res("MAIL_PASSWORD"),
    MAIL_FROM="admin@acsebs.com",
    MAIL_PORT=res("MAIL_PORT"),
    MAIL_SERVER=res("MAIL_SERVER"),
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="send attachment email service",
    MAIL_TLS=res("MAIL_TLS"),
    MAIL_SSL=res("MAIL_SSL"),
    USE_CREDENTIALS=res("USE_CREDENTIALS"),
    VALIDATE_CERTS=res("VALIDATE_CERTS")
))

background_tasks.add_task(fm.send_message, message)

return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "email has been sent"})
```

### Posting data through Swagger UI:

[image]

### The error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with your code, but with Swagger UI when sending multiple values for the same field. As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70644518/17865804), Swagger UI incorrectly adds all items as a single item to the list, separated by comma (you can confirm that by looking at the second screenshot you provided, under the "Curl" section). For example, when you pass two or more email addresses to your endpoint through Swagger UI, they are sent as:

```
['user1@example.com, user2@example.com']
```

instead of:

```
['user1@example.com', 'user2@example.com']
```

Hence, the error is raised, as `'user1@example.com, user2@example.com'` (all together as a single string) is not a valid email address. If you sent a request using HTML `<form>` or JavaScript `fetch`—similar to Method 1 and Method 3 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804)—you would see that your code would work just fine.

**Note 1:** Use a different `<input>` element for each `email` address, but use the same `name` value for all (i.e., `emails`, which is the name of the parameter defined in the endpoint).

**Note 2:** On a side note, be aware that the "the most important part to make a parameter `Optional` is the part `= None`", as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73261442/17865804) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73198957/how-to-exclude-optional-unset-values-from-a-pydantic-model-using-fastapi/73261442#comment129383096_73199363). You seem to have defined your `files` parameter in your endpoint with the `Optional` keyword, but using `= File(...)` or ignoring that part at all, would make `files` a *required* field; hence, make sure to use `= File(None)`, if you want it to be optional instead.

#### Example:

```py
@app.post("/email")
def send_email(emails: List[EmailStr] = Form(...),
              files: Optional[List[UploadFile]] = File(None)):
    return emails


@app.get('/emailForm', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def index():
    return """
    <html>
       <body>
          <form method="POST" action="/email" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <label for="email1">Email 1:</label>
             <input type="text" id="email1" name="emails"><br><br>
             <label for="email2">Email 2:</label>
             <input type="text" id="email2" name="emails"><br><br>
             <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
    """
```

### Adjust the endpoint to work with Swagger UI

If you need to use Swagger UI and would like your endpoint to work when submitting requests through there as well, here is a solution, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70644518/17865804). Perform a check on the `length` of the emails list, and if it is equal to `1` (meaning that the list contains a single item), then split this item using the comma delimiter to get the actual list of email addresses. Finally, loop through the list to validate each email using the [`email-validator`](https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator), which is used by Pydantic behind the scenes.

#### Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, UploadFile, File, Form, HTTPException, status
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
from typing import List, Optional


def check_email(email: str):
    try:
        validation = validate_email(email, check_deliverability=False)
        return validation.email
    except EmailNotValidError as e:
        raise HTTPException(detail=f"'{email}' is not a valid email address. {str(e)}",
                            status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)


def email_checker(emails: List[str] = Form(...)):
    if len(emails) == 1:
        emails = [item.strip() for item in emails[0].split(',')]

    return [check_email(email) for email in emails]


@app.post("/email")
def send_email(emails: List[str] = Depends(email_checker)):
    return emails
```

Comment: Ohh I see, so I just need to separate the form but a normal str List with comma through a loop then add it again to a validation without using EmailStr, Okay thank you Chris, let me try it I'll tell you the result later

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your endpoint accepts a JSON object where you have to provide the types properly due pydantic validation, why don't you just don't provide the request in a JSON format like:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://10.11.12.110:8000/file' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "filename": ["fileA", "fileB", "fileC"],
  "email": ["user1@example.com", "user2@example.com"]
}'
```