# How to pass a list of Form data using FastAPI?

Tags: python, forms, fastapi, form-data, pydantic

After passing data like below, I am getting `['1,3']`,  but this is not a list of data.

**Input data**
[image: Input data]

**Backend**
[image: Backend]

I need the output to be like `['1','3']`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please include the relevant information as _text_ in your question. Images have bad accessibility for those that have trouble seeing, can't be searched for properly, makes it hard to copy-and-paste code for testing and requires the reader to switch back and forth between code and the question.

Comment: Please have a look at this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74067930/17865804) as well